# Mixing C# and VB.Net in ASP.Net error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm trying to mix C# and VB.Net in my project. However I'm getting an error. I already put this lines of codes in my web.config unfortunately still I'm getting an error;

```html
<compilation debug="true">
    <codeSubDirectories>
      <add directoryName="VB" />
      <add directoryName="CSharp" />
    </codeSubDirectories>
  </compilation>
  
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
                type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
                type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Here's the error that I'm getting;

[image]

I already look into these posts, [here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/11afc6c9-d7c7-4059-8875-489f808f1cd0.aspx), [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1280134.aspx?which%20is%20not%20allowed%20since%20they%20need%20to%20be%20compiled%20together), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350398/is-it-possible-to-add-two-language-code-files-i-e-c-sharp-and-vb-net-to-app-cod), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339776/mixing-vb-net-and-c-sharp-code-in-an-asp-net-web-site-project/2339827#2339827). But still I'm getting an error. How to fix this? Thank you.

**EDIT**
Whole web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="VB" />
        <add directoryName="CSharp" />
      </codeSubDirectories>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @LeiYang what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: @LeiYang This is not true. You can mix C# and VB in the same project provided it's only in the `.aspx` files (not code-behind files) and you don't mix two languages in the same file.

Comment: Have you tried changing or adding a targetFramework?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Yes, I already tried that too.

Comment: @LeiYang Not true. You can have both in the same project. Joshua please post your entire web.config. You have an error somewhere else most likely not related to mixing languages.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins as you can see in the picture, the red highlighted is in <compilation> tag. And when I remove the these lines of codes and stick to only one language, there's no error occurring.

Comment: When you right click on your project and choose properties what is your target framework?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined* message will appear if you're trying to run a .NET 3.5 project in .NET 4.x application pool, since machine.config of .NET 4.x already has `scriptResourceHandler` section (you can check in `%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`):

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">

        <!-- this section causing duplicate error for .NET 3.5 projects -->
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        ...
    </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

Also if you're checking web.config in the same directory as machine.config, the `ScriptResourceHandler` is already registered there:

```
<httpHandlers>
    ...

    <!-- this handler is already registered in .NET 4.x default web.config -->
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>

    ...
</httpHandlers>
```

FYI, I found that `configSections` element on .NET 3.5 projects has `scriptResourceHandler` section like this:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
   </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Try remove duplicated `scriptResourceHandler` section in `configSections` marked with version `3.5.0.0` above and try to build again, or if you don't want to upgrade the project just change IIS application pool to use version 2.0 instead.

**NB:** I tried to create a new MVC project from template in VS 2010 using .NET 3.5 and found that both C# & VB are available as `compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"` & `compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript"`.

References:

[MSDN Blog: There is a duplicate scriptResourceHandler section defined](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/10/01/there-is-a-duplicate-scriptresourcehandler-section-defined/)

[IIS7 deployment - duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387322/iis7-deployment-duplicate-system-web-extensions-scripting-scriptresourcehandl)

Comment: You're right, I doubled the <compilation> tag and its already registered if that's what it means. Now, it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your error message. You can run `C#` and `VB` in the same project:

[image]

As the error message states:

> There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined. The issue is because your are running a .net 3.5-based application in Net 4.0

The reason you are having the error is your full `web.config`, which I requested you post in full, has section definitions that are already included in the root web.config in .NET 4.0 default .config (see %windir%\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config)

Comment: I don't know what it means in _The issue is because your are running a .net 3.5-based application in Net 4.0_ yet, I'm using 4.6.1 framework. Do the **duplicate** saying I have a duplication of tag or something?